# Content in only tab 1 is updated in Jquery ui, not tab 2 and tab 3

Tags: php, jquery-ui, web-applications, jquery-ui-tabs, updates

I created tabs using Jquery UI and for each tab, when user open the tab, the tab shows original image which user suppose to edit and then the edited file is saved in the server. Then that edited image is retrieved from the server to display to user by using same tab.

When user uses first tab, it shows original image and updated images properly but when he uses any other tabs, the tab only load the original image and never show the updated image although it is successfully saved in the server.

Comment: We'll need a little more code than that. Like, what does your save and load script look like as that seems to be the root of the problem

Comment: i may provide you some custom tabbing plugin made as jQuery extension. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the console information (Net tab in Firebug for Firefox) to check when the request is post to the server. If the post is before image saved in the server, you may easily find a way out. If not, check if it is the error caused by jQuery tab cache.

Here's the way to enable cache. The tabs will load when you click the tab for the first time. If this is after you changed image in another tab, this should work.

```
$("#rightTabs").tabs({
    cache: true
});
$("#rightTabs").tabs("option", "cache", true );
```